# Value of a input number in jQuery return empty string if contains dash

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Input accept dash and when i write: number, dash(example: *5-*)
.val() or .get(0).value return empty string.

How to deny dash for input with type number?

```js
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
  var value = $("#test").val();
  $("#result").text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test" type="number" name="test" value="1" max="999" min="1">

<p id="result">Result: <b id="reward"></b></p>
```

Comment: A number can't have a dash in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of `5-` is not a valid number, and as such, when jQuery attempts to get the value of the numeric input (`<input type='number' />`), it treats it as a number.

I suggest that you change your input to `type='text'` and handle non-numeric input.